# How can I make dynamic cell width for default layout with horizontal scrolling and equal cell space with leading Swift + iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I am looking a Horizontal Scrolling UICollectionView with 3 rows and dynamic width, cell not align to the left like the image below as android horizontal scrolling :

[image]

SetUpCollectionView Code-

```
func setUpCollectionView() {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionView.ScrollDirection.horizontal
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 16
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 12

    layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
    collectionView.semanticContentAttribute = UISemanticContentAttribute.forceLeftToRight
    collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .always
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout}
```

Here is collectionView code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let extraSpace : CGFloat = 50.0

    return CGSize(width: (self.viewModels?.car_problems?[indexPath.item].problem?.size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)]).width ?? 34) + extraSpace, height: 32)

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 16
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 12
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 16, bottom: 0, right: 16)
}
```

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: How committed are you to using a collection view? This would be **very** easy with a scroll view and stack views.

Comment: I want to show from left to right (leading) but it is taking more space in the middle of the cell. Can you help me related UICollectionViewFlowLayout?

Comment: OK - not clear what you're trying to do... You posted a "left-aligned equal-spaced" image, and said that's **not** what you want, and a "center-column-aligned" image, with *"Expected result"*... but your comment: *"I want to show from left to right (leading) but it is taking more space in the middle of the cell"* ... doesn't seem to match either of those? Can you manually mock-up an image showing what you ***want***?

Comment: I want to show horizontal scroll with dynamic width fixed height 30, equal linespacing and intertimespacing, leading all 3 lines equal as image show-https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eXro.jpg